# Find out the IP address of my server

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm fairly new to PHP and MySQL (please be gentle!), and I want to connect to my server so I can make tests by using

```
$con=mysqli_connect("address","user","password","databaseName");
```

I can't for the life of me figure out the IP address to use! I'm using Filezilla for FTP and google says you can't find it from there, I also tried the backend cPanel but didn't find it anywhere.
How is it done? I guess it can't be too hard... right?

Comment: Is your mysql server running on the same host as your PHP?  If so, then you can just use `localhost` as the address.

Comment: Doesn't your host (if hosted) have all that information for you, and in Cpanel under DB settings? Surely, they must've given you something.

Comment: Your hosting provider should be able to tell you what hostname to use for the database connection.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` is what you want check out all the good stuff in `$_SERVER` [on the official site](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: *Hm...*, I thought of this too, but unsure if that's what the question is about. Will wait if OP agrees.

Comment: Well I'd assume that the database is on the same server as the web server. If not, this won't really help at all. Or would it?...

Answer (score 0):

Using localhost works! Thanks to everyone for the (super fast) response! Victory's $_SERVER response was also very useful!